# double list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there an easy way to comprehend the following

```
words = ["x", "mouse", "looloo", "google", "foo"]
terms = set()
for i in xrange(len(words)):
    terms = terms.union([" ".join(words[j:j + len(words) - i]) for j in xrange(len(words))])
return sorted(terms, key=len, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Did you want to put the outer for loop into the list comprehension as well?

Comment: Please provide a description of what you want to achieve, provide inputs, desired outputs. Otherwise people won't likely help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put multiple loops in a list comprehension by listing them in the same order as you would when using nested for loops.

Something like:

```
terms = set([" ".join(words[j:j + len(words) - i])
               for i in xrange(len(words)) for j in xrange(len(words))])
```

But I find your algorithm rather hard to read as it is, so I am not even sure this will do what you want.

Comment: I think I would write this as `indices = itertools.combinations(range(len(words)+1), 2); terms = sorted(set(' '.join(words[i:j]) for i,j in indices), key=len, reverse=True)`, IIUC, or maybe without the `set`, depending on intent.  With the `set`, duplicates are removed, but the final order is nondeterministic.

Comment: And this could be 20 characters of APL.  But it's not exactly readable.